# How to track score in Constellations

Tags: constellations

In the [Constellations](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/827615927/constellations-the-game-of-stargazing-and-the-nigh) game the rules say that there are 44 point tokens for tracking scores, but they are hidden from players until the end of the game. What does it mean "hidden"? Should there be one person counting and not giving out the current score, or each player should keep tokens in secret, or they just belong to each player and there is no indication of who is leading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at [the rulebook](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/153544/constellations-rulebook-and-stargazing-handbook) right now, and here's the text for the point tokens on page 4 (emphasis mine):

> ## 44 Point Tokens
>
> Points are tracked using Star Tokens, which remain hidden from *other* players until the game is over. Tokens come in 1, 5, 10, 25, and 50 point designations

Based on this, the conclusion I draw is that each player's individual score is technically hidden information - that is, each player knows their score but not any other player's score. The point tokens should be used to track scores on a per-player basis, but players are not required to reveal their collected Point Tokens to other players until the end of the game. In practice, this basically means making a stack of point tokens with 1s on top and 25s and 50s on bottom

It's worth noting that in this setup, because the events that give points is public knowledge, it is possible for a player to keep track of another player's point total.